# How to create a dataframe with number of row having value above of zero for specifics columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
name  skill_1  skill_2
john  2        0
james 0        1
```

I would like to have a count of the rows above of zero for each columns starting with "skill".

Expected output for the new dataframe:

```
skills   count
skill_1  1   
skill_2  1
```

How can I do it with Pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df.filter(like="skill").gt(0).sum(axis=0).to_frame("count")
```

- `filter` for the columns that include `"skill"`
- Mark those entries that are `g`reater `t`han `0` as `True` and others as `False`
- Sum row-wise (`axis=0`) where `True` will be treated as `1` and `False` `0` to get the counts
- Convert `to` data`frame`

to get

```
         count
skill_1      1
skill_2      1
```

Comment: this is a really nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just filter by the condition on the `"skill"` columns:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','skill_1','skill_2'],
                  data=[['john',2,0],
                   ['james',0,1]])

skill_cols = [x for x in df.columns if 'skill' in x]

subset_df = df[df[skill_cols] > 0][skill_cols]
column_count = subset_df.count()
```